# Where should images be located for an application with more then 500 images

Tags: android

I'm thinking about a project that should have more than 500 images. (each image about 20kb)
The application will show an image for every question. So it will show an image per 5-10 seconds. So I'm not sure if I should put images in a server. Because it takes sometime to download and of course costs much data for mobile internet. On the other hand if I put them in application, size will be much for the app.

So should I put them in the application or to a server ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You've answered your own question...

Comment: If the images are really never going to chance, I would store them locally in the app.  If they are frequently changing you can host them on a server somewhere, but cache them till the "expire".

Comment: The app size will be about 10mb with the numbers you gave. That's well within an acceptable size for a graphics-heavy app. I would include them with the APK.

Comment: @njtman The images will change frequently, I think. Well, they are movie images and there will always be new movies so new images. In this case I should put them to server? If so, what should be the scenario to download them ? – Mtok 21 secs ago   edit

Comment: @wblaschko as I said I will add new images frequently, at least once in a month. So what should I do ?

Comment: Is every user going to see every one of the 500 images (almost an hour at 5 secs each)? I would load them as they are requested (20kb, on a fast server, should load relatively quickly) and then cache. If you're showing a slideshow, perhaps load 10-20 at a time and then call for more when you're nearing the end. I would look at Picasso if you're just doing images, or Volley if you're doing images and text to dynamically load images. They are both pretty mature libraries at this point and both handle caching.

Comment: @wblaschko the work is just with images. Image comes to screen, user answers, another image comes to screen, user answers... (So if they keep finding out the right answer 500 times, they see all :-P )

Comment: I would say that if you're changing more than once a month, you should dynamically load the images as needed and cache them on the device. Put a disclaimer saying that the app will use a reasonable amount of data--but even so, it should be less than downloading a full 10mb APK every month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are required, I wouldn't make the app download it at first start like mentioned by Damandeep.

Reason: If the user download and install the app, he has internet connection (otherwise download wouldn't be possible). So in that case, let him download a bit more, shouldn't hurt him.

If you download the images on the first start, there is no guarantee that the internet connection is still there and the user might be surprised. So basically he is annoyed before even using your app.

So if the images barely change (only with app updates): Put it in the APK. (like njtman said in his comment)

Comment: The images will change frequently, I think. Well, they are movie images and there will always be new movies so new images. In this case I should put them to server? If so, what should be the scenario to download them ?

Comment: But you need to change more then only images for the new movies, right? So you need either a real server solution or regular updates. For later solution I would still recommend putting them in the apk

Comment: So you think that I will put them in the apk and update every month ? DO you think that updating apk once in a month is not too often ?

Comment: I have apps updating at least once a week. Advantage of updates is: your user will be reminded that he has your app installed. It is like PR for free :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend downloading the images to sdcard data folder of app on the first run only.
This would keep the app size small and wont cause much data usage.
Use the ASyncTask to download images